# error trying to create a list: expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a list of ids as follows:

```
triggers = {
  cluster_instance_ids = "${list(aws_instance.controller.id, aws_instance.gateway.id, join(",", aws_instance.workers.*.id))}"
}
```

however, applying results in:

> triggers (cluster_instance_ids): '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the `list` function. It needs a string as the error mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`triggers` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html#triggers) of the `null_resource` resource takes a map of strings (eg `map[string]string{}`) as your error message points out when it attempts to read the value of the `cluster_instance_ids` as a string and fails with:

> triggers (cluster_instance_ids): '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'

Removing the unnecessary `list` function should fix the issue as you're left with a concatenated string:

```
triggers = {
  cluster_instance_ids = "${aws_instance.controller.id, aws_instance.gateway.id, join(",", aws_instance.workers.*.id)}"
}
```

In your case, while you are thinking of it being a list of instance IDs, the `triggers` block is just looking for something to change to know that it should be, well, triggered, so it doesn't actually matter what the data type is and so a string is the easiest option. In fact, you already had a list in your `aws_instance.workers.*.id` which you transformed into a string by using the [`join` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#join-delim-list-).